# Merge Multiple Excel Sheets Into Summary Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to allow the user to copy from multiple Excel workbooks and merge the data into a Summary sheet.

```
Sub Merge()
        Dim DestWB As Workbook, WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet, SourceSheet As String

        Set DestWB = ActiveWorkbook
        SourceSheet = "Input"
        startrow = 7
        FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
        Title:="Select the workbooks to merge.", MultiSelect:=True)
        If IsArray(FileNames) = False Then
            If FileNames = False Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        For n = LBound(FileNames) To UBound(FileNames)
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileNames(n), ReadOnly:=True)
            For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
                If WS.Name = SourceSheet Then
                    With WS
                        If .UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                            dr = DestWB.Worksheets("Input").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            lastrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            For j = lastrow To startrow Step -1
                                If Range("E" & j) <> "Requirements Manager" And Range("E" & j) <> "R & D Lead" And Range("E" & j) <> "Technical" And Range("E" & j) <> "Analyst" Then Rows(j).Delete
                            Next
                            lastrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            If lastrow >= startrow Then
                                .Range("A" & startrow & ":AQ" & lastrow).Copy
                                DestWB.Worksheets("Input").Cells(dr, "A").PasteSpecial xlValues
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next WS
            WB.Close savechanges:=False
        Next n
    End Sub
```

The code works fine but I'm stuck with a problem related to the copying of the information, which is this line of code:

```
  .Range("A" & startrow & ":AQ" & lastrow).Copy
```

I need to change this so that it takes into account two ranges. These are columns "B:AD" and "AF:AQ", but I'm not sure how to do this.

I just wondered wehether someone could possibly take a look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may go about solving this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the following I assume that you indeed **don't** want column A copied to the destination workbook and sheet.

You could use `Union` to copy paste it in one go (then any columns in between it will not be reflected when pasting:

```
                        If lastrow >= startrow Then
                            Union(.Range("B" & startrow & ":AD" & lastrow), .Range("AF" & startrow & ":AQ" & lastrow).Copy
                            DestWB.Worksheets("Input").Cells(dr, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
                        End If
```

If you want it pasted with room between it as well then you could simply r3epeat the copy and paste lines:

```
                        If lastrow >= startrow Then
                            .Range("B" & startrow & ":AD" & lastrow).Copy
                            DestWB.Worksheets("Input").Cells(dr, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
                            .Range("AF" & startrow & ":AQ" & lastrow).Copy
                            DestWB.Worksheets("Input").Cells(dr, "AF").PasteSpecial xlValues
                        End If
```

Comment: Hi @K_B, thank you so very much for taking the time to reply to my post. I went for the second option and it works perfectly! All the very best and kind regards